# learning c without compiling to an *.exe?

Tags: c, tcc

I picked up a copy of tiny c compiler (TCC) so i can do some c programming at work.  Unfortunately, a new network security policy prohibits non-IT personnel from downloading/saving exe files.  Of course, each time I try to complile helloworld.c the boss gets notified that I'm a malicious haxor...

My question -- is some sort of c interpreter or environment that i can practice c programming? Or some method to compile my programs in a different way to test them without inadvertantly circumventing security measures?

Comment: Use an online C interpreter, like this one: http://codepad.org/

Comment: You can't save files *anywhere*?  shared network drive, personal user folder, temp directory, etc?  Seems unlikely.

Comment: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: If they have such a strict policy in place, then I doubt they would want you to be running any programs of your own making. Either have them make you an exception to this policy or do your learning somewhere else.

Comment: He can't create executable files. Seems plausible to me.

Comment: There are a many online C++ compilers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator but you should make sure using them confirms to your office policy

Comment: was actually a good question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions -- sorry it wasn't in keeping with the scope, i thought it was at time of writing.  My intended question was not so much "can you recommend a program" but rather "can c be tested without making an exe".  I have plenty to go on here, again, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try [ideone](http://ideone.com/) it gives you a web based front end with the possibilities to compile code and and run it. the output of the program is then printed on the page.

Comment: This is a good fix, as is compileonline.com and some other suggestions. I assume then there is no way to test code using TCC without compiling it into an exe. That's all right, for I have been shown a gold mine.

Comment: I recently learned that one advantage that CodePad and Stacked-Crooked have is that you can use `boost` there.

Answer (score 1):

There are many online C++ compilers available now, the most complete list that I have seen is the one on the [Get Started](http://isocpp.org/get-started) page from [isocpp.org](http://isocpp.org/).

Unfortunately `Cameau's` seems to be gone for good. `LiveWorkspace` has been in maintenance mode for a while and it is not clear when it is coming back, which is unfortunate since it has a simple interface and when it was working allowed you to switch between `gcc`, `clang` and `intel` very easily.

Of the ones that are left [`Stacked-Crooked`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) is the most powerful, you have a full command line available and you can save files and therefore uses multiple files in your project.

The `isocpp` list somehow is missing [`codepad`](http://codepad.org/) which although rather primitive along with `Stacked-Crooked` allows you to use [`boost`](http://www.boost.org/).

[`godbolt`](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) is kind of the odd man out here in that you can't actually run your program there but it shows you the assembly generated. Although you can achieve the same effect on `Stacked-Crooked` using something like this on the command line:

```
g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -S main.cpp && cat main.s
```

and you can use other useful command line options like `-fdump-tree-original` etc...

**Update**

I recently discovered [`Rextester`](http://rextester.com/) which apparently started out as a `regex` tester for `.net` but now support `C++` and many other languages. It is very usable and allows for live cooperation which is a feature that stands out.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the code (if it is a single file) directly from tcc without creating an executable. Use the commad line argument `-run`.

On my system, tcc is installed in \Utils\tcc.
The file hello.c is a basic "Hello World" source file.

First I did a "dir", then 'executed' the source without creating an executable, and finally another "dir" to show nothing was created.

```
C:\misc>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BC80-0D15

 Directory of C:\misc

2013-06-03  13:12              .
2013-06-03  13:12              ..
2013-06-03  13:11                86 hello.c
               1 File(s)             86 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  14,364,372,992 bytes free

C:\misc>\utils\tcc\tcc -run hello.c
Hello, World!

C:\misc>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BC80-0D15

 Directory of C:\misc

2013-06-03  13:12              .
2013-06-03  13:12              ..
2013-06-03  13:11                86 hello.c
               1 File(s)             86 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  14,364,372,992 bytes free

C:\misc>
```

Comment: thanks you very much! this is a very simple solution and it works as advertised. I sincerely appreciate it.